# Rails project not loading CSS in test environment causing problems with circleCI tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am having issues running tests with cucumber in CircleCI because the CSS files are not loading properly.

I ran the project in the test environment `RAILS_ENV=test rails s` and it is not loading the CSS (even though I can see the CSS generated by `RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:precompile`). It will only load correctly if I run `rake assets:precompile` before. But how can I do this for circleCI?

Likewise, locally I can run `bundle exec cucumber` without any failing tests (if I run `rake assets:precompile` before), but if I then user CircleCI to run the same tests I get the same failing tests as if I delete the `public/assets` folder and run `bundle exec cucumber` locally.

In my `environment/test.rb` I have added the files to `config.assets.precompile`

This is my `applicatin.scss`:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./shared
 *= require_tree ./tenants
 *= require_tree ./pages
 */
```

My `Gemfile`:

```
ruby '2.5.5'

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '5.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'haml-rails', "~> 1.0"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'd3_rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'sass', '3.7.1'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

gem 'date'
gem 'fileutils'
gem 'browser'
gem 'bugsnag'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
gem 'acts_as_list', '0.9.5'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'gon', '~> 6.2.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'handlebars_assets'
gem 'iconv', "~> 1.0.2"
gem 'non-stupid-digest-assets'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3'
gem 'unicorn', '~> 5.4.1'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'mixpanel-ruby'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'doc_raptor', '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'validates_lengths_from_database'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.3'
gem 'virtus'
gem 'curb'
gem 'rb-readline'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '4.7.3'
  gem 'guard-spork', '2.1.0'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'jasmine-rails'
  gem 'teaspoon-jasmine'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'daemons'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'
  gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.16.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'
  gem 'heroku-deflater'
end
```

`CircleCI` config file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/xxxx/xxxxxx
    parallelism: 1
    shell: /bin/bash --login
    # CircleCI 2.0 does not support environment variables that refer to each other the same way as 1.0 did.
    # If any of these refer to each other, rewrite them so that they don't or see https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#interpolating-environment-variables-to-set-other-environment-variables .
    environment:
      CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
      CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    # In CircleCI 1.0 we used a pre-configured image with a large number of languages and other packages.
    # In CircleCI 2.0 you can now specify your own image, or use one of our pre-configured images.
    # The following configuration line tells CircleCI to use the specified docker image as the runtime environment for you job.
    # We have selected a pre-built image that mirrors the build environment we use on
    # the 1.0 platform, but we recommend you choose an image more tailored to the needs
    # of each job. For more information on choosing an image (or alternatively using a
    # VM instead of a container) see https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/
    # To see the list of pre-built images that CircleCI provides for most common languages see
    # https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.5.5-browsers-legacy
        environment:
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: postgres
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: xxxx-test

    steps:
      # Machine Setup
      #   If you break your build into multiple jobs with workflows, you will probably want to do the parts of this that are relevant in each
      # The following `checkout` command checks out your code to your working directory. In 1.0 we did this implicitly. In 2.0 you can choose where in the course of a job your code should be checked out.
      - checkout
      # Prepare for artifact and test results  collection equivalent to how it was done on 1.0.
      # In many cases you can simplify this from what is generated here.
      # 'See docs on artifact collection here https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/'
      - run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
      # Dependencies
      #   This would typically go in either a build or a build-and-test job when using workflows
      # Restore the dependency cache
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          # This branch if available
          - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
          # Default branch if not
          - v1-dep-master-
          # Any branch if there are none on the default branch - this should be unnecessary if you have your default branch configured correctly
          - v1-dep-
      # The following line was run implicitly in your 1.0 builds based on what CircleCI inferred about the structure of your project. In 2.0 you need to be explicit about which commands should be run. In some cases you can discard inferred commands if they are not relevant to your project.
      - run: echo -e "export RAILS_ENV=test\nexport RACK_ENV=test" >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: sed -i.bak "/gem ['\"]growl_notify\|autotest-fsevent\|rb-appscript\|rb-fsevent['\"].*, *$/ N; s/\n *//g; /gem ['\"]growl_notify\|autotest-fsevent\|rb-appscript\|rb-fsevent['\"]/ d" Gemfile
      - run: 'bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3 '
      # Save dependency cache
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
          paths:
          # This is a broad list of cache paths to include many possible development environments
          # You can probably delete some of these entries
          - vendor/bundle
          - ~/.bundle
      # SETUP DB:
      - run:
          name: Database Setup
          command: |
            bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace
            bundle exec rake db:migrate
          environment:
            DATABASE_URL: "postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/xxxx"
      # Test
      #   This would typically be a build job when using workflows, possibly combined with build
      # The following line was run implicitly in your 1.0 builds based on what CircleCI inferred about the structure of your project. In 2.0 you need to be explicit about which commands should be run. In some cases you can discard inferred commands if they are not relevant to your project.
      - run:
          command: bundle exec rspec --color --format progress spec
          environment:
            RAILS_ENV: test
            RACK_ENV: test

      - run:
          command: |
            mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/cucumber
            bundle exec cucumber --format json --out $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/cucumber/cucumber.cucumber
          environment:
            RAILS_ENV: test
            RACK_ENV: test
      # # This is based on your 1.0 configuration file or project settings
      # - run: bundle exec rake teaspoon
    # Deployment
    # Your existing circle.yml file contains deployment steps.
    # The config translation tool does not support translating deployment steps
    # since deployment in CircleCI 2.0 are better handled through workflows.
    # See the documentation for more information https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/
  deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
    working_directory: ~/xxx/xxxxx
    environment:
      HEROKU_APP: "XXXXXXX"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Deploy Master to Heroku
          command: |
            git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP.git master

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Comment: If it only works with `rake assets:precompile`, can't you run this command on CircleCI?

Comment: @GProst I did, but it does not solve the problem in CircleCI

Comment: Try putting `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )` in Config > initializers > assets.rb let me know if that works. (Don't worry, it also precompiles .scss files.)

Comment: Try getting a post-failure SSH session, so you can examine the state of the app. This has often shed light on an otherwise incomprehensible situation, for me.

Comment: @Jake I did, but did not solve the problem :(

Comment: If you're using Chrome, try running it on an alternative browser. I read something about the latest version of Chrome potentially causing problems [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/new-version-of-chrome-causing-problems-in-tests/30136).

Comment: @marimaf Can you please share the actual error messages you get in CircleCi for your failing tests? You say that tests are failing because CSS files are not loading properly, but how do you know thats why the tests fail?

Comment: Is the loading of the CSS relevant for your test results, or is it just a question of not raising an error?

Comment: @ErvalhouS yes it is relevant, as the tests look for some classes in the html and it is unable to find them

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

config.serve_static_assets = true

in your environments/test.rb

Comment: Yes, it has always been like that, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually [documented by CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#full-example-of-saving-and-restoring-cache) itself. To avoid running precompilation every test use CircleCI's cache feature. You just need to create a `.circleci/config.yml` with your build's configuration. For instance, if you need to test on a machine with Ruby 2.3 and MySQL running `rspec` and `cucumber` you file would be much like the following:

```
docker:
  - image: customimage/ruby:2.3-node-phantomjs-0.0.1
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      RACK_ENV: test
  - image: circleci/mysql:5.6

steps:
  - checkout
  - run: cp config/{database_circleci,database}.yml

  # Run bundler
  # Load installed gems from cache if possible, bundle install then save cache
  # Multiple caches are used to increase the chance of a cache hit

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - gem-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        - gem-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}
        - gem-cache-v1

  - run: bundle install --path vendor/bundle

  - save_cache:
      key: gem-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - vendor/bundle

  - run: bundle exec rubocop
  - run: bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load --trace
  - run: bundle exec rake factory_girl:lint

  # Precompile assets
  # Load assets from cache if possible, precompile assets then save cache
  # Multiple caches are used to increase the chance of a cache hit

  - restore_cache:
      keys:
        - asset-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
        - asset-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}
        - asset-cache-v1

  - run: bundle exec rake assets:precompile

  - save_cache:
      key: asset-cache-v1-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Environment.CIRCLE_SHA1 }}
      paths:
        - public/assets
        - tmp/cache/assets/sprockets

  - run: bundle exec rspec
  - run: bundle exec cucumber
```

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but I got the same failing tests.